# search Chain not getting accepted in vespa

Tags: n-gram, vespa

I am trying to add a searcher code in my java/ai/vespa/example path. The searcher code basically changes the Ngram Searcher from AND to OR.
I added this searcher code path reference to services.xml

```
<search>
        <chain id='ORgram' inherits='vespa' 
excludes='com.yahoo.search.querytransform.NGramSearcher'>
        <searcher bundle='gram-searcher' id='ai.vespa.examples.OrNGramSearcher'/>
        </chain>
    </search>
```

But, when I am trying to add this searchChain to my query it is giving me an error.

```
 **'message': "No search chain named 'ORgram' was found"**
```

Neither the NGram Searcher is getting excluded from the results nor the new OR gram searcher is being applied to it.

The searcher code is:-

```
package ai.vespa.example;

import com.yahoo.search.Query;
import com.yahoo.prelude.query.CompositeItem;
import com.yahoo.prelude.query.OrItem;
import com.yahoo.prelude.query.HasIndexItem;
import com.yahoo.search.querytransform.NGramSearcher;
import com.yahoo.language.Linguistics;

public class OrNGramSearcher extends NGramSearcher {

    public OrNGramSearcher(Linguistics linguistics) {
        super(linguistics);
    }

    @Override
    protected CompositeItem createGramRoot(HasIndexItem term, Query query) {
        return new OrItem();
    }

}
```

Other than that I am also following the maven layout which has pom.xml and the bundle id which I am using in the services.xml for  is the same as the artifactID in the pom.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you run

```
mvn install
```

before

```
vespa deploy
```

to build the new application package.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It worked.
But when I am making changes to the schema, and then redeploying using the curl command:-
`curl --header Content-Type:application/zip --data-binary @application/application.zip localhost:19071/application/v2/tenant/default/prepareandactivate`
The changes are not reflected while querying.
I wanted to ask that while working with java components, do we need to do mvn build every time to deploy changes to schema or can it be done directly without doing mvn install everytime? Can't the changes be reflected directly on the schema using the usual curl command?

Comment: You need to run mvn build each time as that builds the application.zip which is what is deployed.